# How to implement VBO double buffering in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I want to increase performance in my WebGL project by setting up VBO double buffering. Although there are plenty of articles on this topic, I failed to find one with a coding example.

I tried the following:

```
// Initial setup...

var buff1 = gl.createBuffer();
var buff2 = gl.createBuffer();
var buffActive = buff1;

// For each frame, change the verticies data and then ...

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffActive);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, start, count);

buffActive = (buffActive === buff2) ? buff1 : buff2;
```

The calls to `gl.bindBuffer` and `gl.bufferData` work fine. However, `gl.drawArrays` always renders using only the data from `buff1`. I assumed `gl.drawArrays` would render using whichever VBO is currently bound to `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER`, but apparently that's not the case.

Does anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement VBO double buffering then you need to ensure calls to `gl.vertexAttribPointer` and `gl.enableVertexAttribArray` for vertex attribute data (stored as interleaved data in `vertArray`) are made every time the VBOs switch, rather than just during setup. Otherwise, your vertex attribute pointers will always be referencing data in the first VBO, and that VBO will now only be updated every other frame as a consequence of double buffering. The calls to `gl.vertexAttribPointer` and `gl.enableVertexAttribArray` must now be made after switching VBOs and before `gl.drawArrays`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you have bound both `buff1` and `buff2` to the same buffer, `vertArray`.
A better thing to do is create two vertex arrays (say, `vertArray1` and `vertArray2`) and
to bind each vertex array to a separate buffer object during the initial setup (and not each frame, because
`bufferData()` destroys and reinitializes a buffer object's data, which may be an
expensive operation if doing so requires uploading the data to the GPU).

Here's an example:

```
// Initial setup
var buff1 = gl.createBuffer();
var buff2 = gl.createBuffer();
// Associate the buffer data once during initial setup.
// Note that we use two vertex arrays, vertArray1 and vertArray2,
// rather than one
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buff1);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertArray1, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buff2);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertArray2, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
var buffActive = buff1;
var vertArrayActive = vertArray1;

// For each frame:
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffActive);
// No need to re-load the buffer data
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, start, count);
buffActive = (buffActive === buff2) ? Buff1 : buff2;
vertArrayActive = (vertArrayActive === vertArray2) ? VertArray1 : vertArray2;
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried setting up separate vertex arrays for each VBO as you suggested, but it made no difference in my case. I'm using two VBOs not because I have two different sets of vertices data, but because I want to use two VBOs for the _same_ vertices data for performance reasons (i.e., to prevent GPU stalling due to `gl.bufferData` calls). Since I have vertex attribute data that can potentially change every frame due to user input I have to call `gl.bufferData` (or perhaps `gl.bufferSubData`) on every frame for which that data changes.

Answer (score 0):

As I know WebGL automatically implements double buffering.